# calculating variance after iteration for each cell in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, variance

How can I calculate the variance of each cell in a matrix after a loop?

I have this so far:

```
  m = matrix(0,10,10)
  n = 100   
  v = 1

  rad2 <- function(matrix, repeats, v) {
  idx <- sample(length(matrix), repeats, replace = TRUE) # indices
  flip <- sample(c(-1, 1), repeats, replace = TRUE) # subtract or add
  newVal <- aggregate(v * flip ~ idx, FUN = sum) # calculate new values for indices
  matrix[newVal[[1]]] <- matrix[newVal[[1]]] + newVal[[2]] # add new values
  variance = M2/(n-1)
  return(matrix)
}
```

So now if I do:

```
rad2(m, n, v)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1    0   -2    1   -2    1     0
 [2,]    1    1    0    0    0    0   -1    2    0    -2
 [3,]   -1    1   -1    1    0    0    0    1   -1    -1
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    -1
 [5,]    0    1    1   -2    0    0    1    0   -1    -1
 [6,]   -2   -3    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    -2
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    2   -1    0   -1     1
 [8,]    2    0   -1    0   -1   -1   -1    0   -1     0
 [9,]    0    0    1    1   -1    1    1    0    0     1
[10,]    0   -3    1    0   -2    0    0   -2   -1     0
```

I want to calculate the variance in each cell after 100 iterations of this function. The output can be in a table or in a vector. There should be 100 values in the end. How can I do this?

**edit:**

If I do this instead:

```
n=10
for (i in 1:n) {
 tmp <- rad(m) 
 m <- tmp
 outv <- unlist(sapply(m, function(x) var(m)))
 finalv <- outv
}
```

I get an output in finalv. But how can I replace the variance value for each cell after each loop in the matrix instead of just writing it over and over again?

Comment: There is an error in your function. M2 should be matrix. Also I would avoid giving objects the names of common functions it causes confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want. Just some simple for functions.

```
newdata=matrix(NA,100,100)
output=NULL
for (i in 1:100){newdata[i,]=as.numeric(rad2(m, n, v))}
for (n in 1:100){output[n]=mean(newdata[,n])}
matrix(output,10,10)
```

A more universal way

```
newdata=matrix(NA,length(m),length(m))
output=NULL
for (i in 1:length(m)){newdata[i,]=as.numeric(rad2(m, n, v))}
for (b in 1:length(m)){output[b]=mean(newdata[,b])}
matrix(output,dim(m)[1],dim(m)[2])
```

Comment: when I change n to 10 instead of 100 and change the for loop to 1:10 I just get NAs..why is that?

Comment: I've made edits that should clarify but loop length should be the length of the m matrix.

Comment: I've made a modification to rad to only accept a matrix. The error I'm getting in your code is "Error in newdata[i, ] = as.numeric(rad(m)) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I was talking about fixing your original rad2 function. `variance = M2/(n-1)` should be `variance = matrix/(n-1)` Make sure you use the second bit of code I gave you starting with `newdata=matrix(NA,length(m),....`. So if you make the edit to rad2 and copy the second code everything works even when changing the dimensions of m. If you're still having problems instal the latest version of R. Really you need to spend some time learning how R actually works. All the information you need to fix your problems is already out there.